# Pass a blank object to a self instance model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to have a parent category of blank/null for a model while entering through a from in Django. Is it possible to pass a null value through the blank form ?

Here's my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    category_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category_parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

And forms.py

```
from django import forms
from backend.models import Category


class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category_parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(), empty_label='None')
    category_image = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('category_name', 'category_code',)
```

I want to have a null value for the parent select field if nothing is selected. Or if I'm entering the first value in the category, it should point null when there's no parent.

Comment: What do you intend to do after passing null value through blank form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm getting this right, but I'm guessing that even with the `empty_label` set to `None` you are still seeing the first category in the list selected.

When you override a `ModelForm` field, like you do now for `category_parent`, you lose the automatically connected `required=False` form correspondent for the `blank=True` in the model.

Try adding `required=False` to the form field, like this:

```
category_parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), empty_label='None', required=False)
```